# Dicionario Python Ordem alfabética e duplicar dicionario já existente

Tags: python, classificação

Pessoal estou com dúvida em como escrever na tela para o usuário os valores do dicionario sem o colchete e em ordem alfabética.
Estou com dúvida também em como fazer dois novos dicionários para selecionar somente os contatos com 18 anos ou mais e o outro com 18 anos ou menos.

Segue o enunciado da questão:
Leia e armazene em um dicionário o nome, a idade e o número do telefone de seus
contatos, sendo que a chave deve ser o nome. Ao digitar uma string vazia para o nome, o
programa interrompe a leitura e se encerra.
Apresente na tela os dados lidos em ordem alfabética pelo nome dos contatos. Uma
possível solução de ordenar alfabeticamente é usar o método sort.
Em seguida, armazene os contatos em outros dois dicionários, utilizando como
critério a idade: menores de 18 anos em um e os maiores em outro dicionário, eliminando
o original. Apresente na tela os dois dicionários resultantes da separação.

Meu código:

```
from operator import itemgetter

nomesContatos = {}

for i in range(0, 300):
    nome = input('Digite o nome do contato: ')
    nome = nome.capitalize()
    grade = []

    if nome == '':
        break

    for j in range(0, 1):
        while True:
            try:
                idade = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
                grade.append(idade)
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Idade inválida...')
                continue

        for k in range(0, 1):
            while True:
                try:
                    telefone = int(input('Digite o telefone: '))
                    grade.append(telefone)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print('Número inválido...')

    nomesContatos[nome] = grade
    print('\n')


for contatos in sorted(nomesContatos, key=nomesContatos.get):
    a = (nomesContatos[contatos])

    print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Pessoal estou com dúvida em como escrever na tela para o usuário os
> valores do dicionario sem o colchete e em ordem alfabética.

Você pode dar sort nas chaves do dicionario e depois interar chave a chave:

```py
nomes=  {
    "Joao":[1,11999999],
    "Maria":[5,21123451],
    "Ana":[6,4123212451],
}

ordem_alfabetica = sorted(nomes.keys())
ordem_alfabetica

#output
>> ['Ana', 'Joao', 'Maria']

for nome in ordem_alfabetica:
  print(f"{nome} --->  Nota : {nomes.get(nome)[0]} ---> telefone : {nomes.get(nome)[1]}")

#ouput
>> Ana --->  Idade: 6 ---> telefone : 4123212451
>> Joao --->  Idade: 1 ---> telefone : 11999999
>> Maria --->  Idade: 5 ---> telefone : 21123451
```

> Estou com dúvida também em como fazer dois novos dicionários para
> selecionar somente os contatos com 18 anos ou mais e o outro com 18
> anos ou menos.

não é necessario fazer 2 dicionários para isso vc pode colocar uma condição e tratar caso a caso, com isso se quiser vc pode criar 2 dicionarios tbm

```py
menor = {}
maior = {}
for nome in ordem_alfabetica:

  if nomes.get(nome)[0] < 18:
    print("Eu tenho menos de 18")
    menor[nome] = nomes[nome]
    #Do Stuff
  else:
    print("Eu tenho 18 ou mais")
    maior[nome] = nomes[nome]
    #Do Stuff
```